# How to install proxychains for Mac Os

Tags: mac, socks-proxy

I tried installing homebrew and then installing proxychains with brew install proxychains-ng. It did not work. I then tried downloading the formula from https://gist.github.com/allenhuang/3792521 without success. Do anyone knows how to install proxychains for mac?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Homebrew works fine for me. `brew install proxychains-ng` installs the proxychains4 executable:

```
$ which proxychains4
/usr/local/bin/proxychains4
```

Is `brew doctor`ok?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Heres the output MacBook-Pro:~ Bob$ proxychains4 nmap -sS 192.168.1.1
[proxychains] config file found: /usr/local/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/local/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
dyld: could not load inserted library '/usr/local/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib' because no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /usr/local/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.11/lib/libproxychains4.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: So you have it installed. Suggest you raise an issue at https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/issues. Would you mind marking this as correct answer too - cheers

Comment: This is another error when trying to start proxychains4 service: proxychains can't load process....: No such file or directory

Comment: Again, I'd suggest any usage problems are best dealt with via GitHub issues at the proxychains-ng repo

Comment: https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/issues/109

Comment: Hey could you show me an output of your proxychain?

Comment: Example at the bottom of here: https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/issues/78

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling proxichains4 (proxychains-ng) with 
`brew rmtree proxychains-ng` ,
confirm and next re-installing whit this command

```
brew install proxychains-ng --universal
```

Comment: why? are you sure? XD

Comment: Error: invalid option: --universal